# How do I check if nested if is not equal to 0 bash

Tags: bash

I have a PC that downloads torrents and moves completed files to a LAN server then continues seeding them. When it's done, the .parts file is removed. At this point I'd like it to move everything to the correct directories. Removing the 2 extra if statements works fine for that but I'd rather not try to run the commands if the files don't exist.

I've tried a few different things in trying to condense this script as much as I can without running useless parts if not needed. I've tried using the following (and more):

```
if [ "$count2" != 0 ]
if [ "$count2" -ne 0 ]
if [ "$count2" -gt 0 ]
```

Last working code:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=`ls -1 *.parts 2>/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/AutoTorrents/ | wc -l`
if [ $count == 0 ]
then
        mv /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/AutoTorrents/*.{mkv,mp4,m4v,avi,txt} /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/Movies/!New_Movies/
        mv /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/AutoTorrents/*.{srt,sub} /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/Movies/!Subtitles/
        mv /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/AutoTorrents/*.{png,jpg,jpeg} /var/www/html/images/
fi
```

What the non-working code I'm trying to get to work looks like currently:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=$(find *.parts 2>/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/AutoTorrents/ | wc -l)
count2=$(find *.{srt,sub} 2>/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/AutoTorrents/ | wc -l)
count3=$(find *.{png,jpg,jpeg} 2>/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/AutoTorrents/ | wc -l)
if [ "$count" == 0 ]
then
        mv /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/AutoTorrents/*.{mkv,mp4,m4v,avi} /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/Movies/!New_Movies/
        if [ "$count2" == 0 ]
            then
                :
            else mv /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/AutoTorrents/*.{srt,sub,txt} /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/Movies/!Subtitles/
        fi
        if [ "$count3" == 0 ]
            then
                :
            else mv /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/AutoTorrents/*.{png,jpg,jpeg} /var/www/html/images/
        fi
fi
```

Comment: FYI, `==` isn't guaranteed to work in `[` across implementations; `=` is the only POSIX-standardized string-comparison operator.

Comment: Bigger picture, though -- why are you structuring your logic this way? Why nest the 2nd and 3rd operations inside the first test? Why separate the data collection from the comparison of the results?

Comment: Also, `find *.srt` almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does, and redirecting stderr to a directory makes no sense at all. `find /var/www/html/uploads/Video/AutoTorrents -name '*.srt'` is more likely to be what you're actually intending to run.

Comment: Mostly I don't really have a reason for why. I'm just trying to get the minimal amount of errors in my log with a functioning code. I'm learning everything as I go from google basically. So, I hope that explains my overthought logic.

Comment: If you're looking for a high-quality learning resource to bash, I recommend the Wooledge [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) pages; the [bash-hackers' wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) is also as a whole really great. Otherwise, there's a lot of junk out there on Google, some of it with disturbingly high PageRank.

Comment: Thank you, I'll add these to my bookmarks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your `find` invocations are all buggy, but because you're redirecting stderr (to a directory, which isn't able to store it), you never see the error message describing the bug, and thus never find out what went wrong.

Consider the following instead:

```sh
dir=/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/AutoTorrents/
count=$(find "$dir" -name '*.parts' | wc -l)
count2=$(find "$dir" '(' -name '*.srt' -o -name '*.sub' ')' -print | wc -l)
count3=$(find "$dir" '(' -name '*.png' -o -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.jpeg' ')' -print | wc -l)
```

...or, even better, follow the advice in [BashFAQ #4](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004), and rely on `nullglob` to make sure globs with no matches expand to empty lists, and `globstar` to enable recursion. The below also uses GNU `xargs` to split up lists of files into lengths `mv` is guaranteed to be able to successfully handle (also relying on the GNU `mv` extension `-t` to put the destination *before* the list of files to be moved, rather than at the end):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[0-3].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0+ needed" >&2; exit 1;; esac

dir=/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/AutoTorrents/
movDest=/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/Movies/
imgDest=/var/www/html/images/

shopt -s nullglob globstar

parts=( "$dir"/**/*.parts )
if (( ${#parts[@]} )); then
  exit 0 # do not run when any *.parts files exist
fi

movs=( "$dir"/**/*.{mkv,mp4,m4v,avi} )
if (( ${#movs[@]} )); then
  printf '%s\0' "${movs[@]}" | xargs -0r mv -t "$movDest/!New_Movies" --
fi

subs=( "$dir"/**/*.{srt,sub} )
if (( ${#subs[@]} )); then
  printf '%s\0' "${subs[@]}" | xargs -0r mv -t "$movDest/!Subtitles" --
fi

imgs=( "$dir"/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg} )
if (( ${#imgs[@]} )); then
  printf '%s\0' "${imgs[@]}" | xargs -0r mv -t "$imgDest" --
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful advice. I attempted to use glob earlier but couldn't really understand how to integrate it with the code I had at the time. One issue though, reading through this I assume it moves .parts to !New_Movies. The .parts is what I'm using to determine if the files are complete. Once the download is done the .parts file is removed by the torrent client. Only then I want to run the mv commands. Everything works changing that to .mp4, but, I don't really understand the code well enough to tell what to change in order to only run if 0 .parts exist with this code.

Comment: See edit. (Not that I'd use this logic myself -- unless you have some kind of locking, operations tend to be race-condition-prone).

Comment: Thank you for everything again! I actually have like 3 systems running together in order to automate a media center that I coded from mostly scratch. My goal is to remove as many external programs as I can. Since I coded everything based on my/google logic, doing it this way helps me to find what system is messing up where, when, and keeps the site looking pretty.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at [incron](https://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=why&lang=en); configure it to start your script every time a `.part` file is deleted, or every time an output file is closed, and there you are.